# Limit of an integral containing a product

Tags: limits, special-functions

I'm stuck on the following problem:
given the integral:
$$I(N)=\int \prod_{k=1}^N \left(k-\frac{k}{x}\right) \, dx$$
calculate the following limit:
$$I_{\infty}(N)=\lim_{x\to\infty}I(N)$$
I know that 
$$I(N)=x(1-x)^{-N}\frac{(x-1)^N}{x^N}\Gamma(N+1)_{2}\tilde F_1(1-N,-N;2-N;x)\frac{1}{1-N}$$
but how can I calculate this limit for $x\to\infty$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the limit of $x \to \infty$ shouldn't you expect asymptote to be $\int \prod_{k=1}^N k \mathrm{d}x = x N!$, and thus the limit is infinity?

Comment: Are the integral limits 1 to infinity and do you mean N approaches infinity instead of of x?

Comment: @Sasha: Ok. So the $I_\infty(N)=\infty$. Thanks.

Comment: Please supply the limits of the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
I_x(N)&=&\int\prod_{k=1}^N\left(k-\frac{k}{x}\right)dx=N!\int\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^Ndx\cr
&=&N!\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^k{N\choose k}\int x^{-k}dx=N!\left[x-N\ln|x|+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}{N\choose k+1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^k\right]+C.
\end{eqnarray}
It follows that
$$
I_\infty(N)=\lim_{x\to \infty}I_x(N)=\lim_{x\to \infty}N!(x-N\ln|x|)=\infty.
$$